# Using MySQL RAND() to avoid ORDER BY RAND()

Tags: mysql

I am storing `RAND()` value in a table on each insert and then I run following query to get random rows from the table.

```
select id from test where random_value >= RAND() LIMIT 5;
```

There are total 456 rows in a table but the random value is only picking up first 20-25 records. I ran many times above query but never got `id > 21`.

You can find queries and results [here](http://pastebin.com/DHgTBERW).

Comment: If it's not a daft question, why do you want to avoid ORDER BY RAND() ?

Comment: http://www.webtrenches.com/post.cfm/avoid-rand-in-mysql That's why you wnat to avoid it

Comment: Do `select id, random_value, RAND(1) AS rand FROM test;` and show us result.

Comment: @Carl Saldanha: You learn something new every day, cheers for that. Looks like I have some code mods to do!

Comment: @Narek Here is the result: http://pastebin.com/9LBN155Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution and it worked perfect!

```
SELECT  rnd_id, rnd_value
FROM    (
        SELECT  @cnt := COUNT(*) + 1,
                @lim := 10
        FROM    t_random_innodb
        ) vars
STRAIGHT_JOIN
        (
        SELECT  r.*,
                @lim := @lim - 1
        FROM    t_random_innodb r
        WHERE   (@cnt := @cnt - 1)
                AND RAND(20090301) < @lim / @cnt
        ) i
```

Source: http://explainextended.com/2009/03/01/selecting-random-rows/

Answer (score 1):

Your `RAND()` changes after every loop. You need to fix it before `SELECT`:

```
SET @r := RAND();
SELECT id, @r
FROM test
WHERE random_value >= @r
LIMIT 5
```

But this is not a good solution because in case of **small** random number you will always get same rows from DB.

For saving performance you can use [this](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/) method. I tried it and it works.

Comment: Pretty much same results are coming on every run

Comment: It's because if your rand for example `0.1` you will always see first 5 rows because almost all results bigger that `0.1`. I wrote about it in answer.

Comment: In order to avoid getting the same rows need to add `ORDER BY random_value` so it gets the **closest** 5. Not just any 5 that meet the condition.